# Can Remoting be inside a class

Tags: apache-flex

Should i keep Remoting Methods outside a class in a seperate AS file or is it possible to call Remoting inside a class.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have your remote objects in the main Application MXML file, but the general rule of thumb is that it is almost always better to move your external calls away from the center of your processes.  This will make the code easier to debug, but it will also make the code easier to maintain down the line.

Actually, Adobe's recommended architecture, Cairngorm, not only abstracts the Remote Objects themselves into a single class (the ServiceLocator class), but they also recommend that everything which is used to handle that class should be abstracted as well.

The RemoteObject in Cairngorm:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/cairngorm_pt5_03.html

Comment: @user98514 Apart from Cairngorm you can also take a look at other Flex micro-architectures to organize your code(seperate service, controller and view classes). [Swiz](http://swizframework.org/) is a good option in my opinion.